# App won't launch; constantly invoking library?

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-launcher

I am trying to launch an Android project, and I am running into the conflict of the application constantly invoking **Android Package Builder** of a referenced library, until the application finally timesout and returns a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Any ideas of what might be happening? The library is needed, so I do not understand why it has become an issue.

Some additional information:
1) I have no errors
2) The main project and library both have Android Package Builder checked off (checked from Project Properties > Builders)
3) There exists an .apk. Not sure if this is related.

What do you think?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: While it would obviously be nice to straighten out the auto install & launch button, if you've already generated an APK which you believe is current, you can manually install that with ADB as a stopgap measure.

Comment: @nikis I am using Eclipse